# How can I add new elements to a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I was trying to add a new element of array to the list with update of one property (id). I want to make it 1 more than length of array.
But I get some weird outputs, with add every new object. All elements are getting array.length +1 value.

I made several variations of this code with `let`, `const` or even operating directly on `this.state.produktsToBuy`, and every time I got the same output

[image]

```
handleAddToShop = (produktToBuy) => {
  const id = this.state.produktsToBuy.length+1;
  produktToBuy.id = id + 1;
  const produktsToBuy = this.state.produktsToBuy;
  produktsToBuy.push(produktToBuy);
  this.setState({produktsToBuy});
};
```

I Should get the output as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
But on the end I get 7,7,7,7,7,7

Comment: What is `produktsToBuy.puenter code heresh(produktToBuy);`? Ah, okay, it's `produktsToBuy.push(produktToBuy);`. Can you fix it in your post?

Comment: Please format your code so that we can read it! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not mutating the state directly. In JS, objects are a reference type. When you assign `this.state.produktsToBuy` to `const produktsToBuy` and push something to `produktsToBuy`, you're actually pushing to the original `this.state.produktsToBuy` and you modify the state.

You can use the spread operator (`...`) to create a shallow copy of the state (`produktsToBuy`):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { name: "test item 1", price: 4.99 },
      { name: "test item 2", price: 7.99 },
      { name: "test item 3", price: 19.99 }
    ],
    produktsToBuy: []
  };

  handleAddToShop = (produktToBuy) => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      produktsToBuy: [
        ...prev.produktsToBuy,
        {
          ...produktToBuy,
          id: prev.produktsToBuy.length + 1
        }
      ]
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {this.state.items.map((item) => (
            <div
              key={item.name}
              style={{
                border: "1px solid #ccc",
                margin: "1rem",
                padding: "1rem",
                textAlign: "center"
              }}
            >
              <h3>{item.name}</h3>
              <p>${item.price}</p>
              <button onClick={() => this.handleAddToShop(item)}>Add</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.produktsToBuy, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, but i want to update the state. it is simply application without backend, and i want to see the change immediately

Comment: The code above updates the state but you should always use `this.setState`.

Comment: And I've just added a live snippet above, you can run it and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should be maintaining all of the previous state if there's anything other than just the produktsToBuy. Also, you always need the functional form of setState if anything you're setting is dependent on the previous state(as is OFTEN the case). And, like Zsolt said, you never mutate the state directly in React. Here's my answer (very similar to @Zsolt Meszaros'). Note: .concat creates a new array, so we don't have to worry about mutating the original.

```
handleAddToShop = (produktToBuy) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        const { produktsToBuy } = prevState;
        return {
            ...prevState,
            produktsToBuy: produktsToBuy.concat([
                {
                    ...produktToBuy,
                    id: produktsToBuy.length + 1,
                },
            ]),
        };
    });
};
```